# How to print and scan structures

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I'm learning how to write structures properly. But I'm not used to fixing up structures. All I want is what the code errors(for structures) mean and how to fix it. Is it similarly to arrays? I know that code has no input but the help I need is just for fixing the errors caused by the structure.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<limits.h>
#define MAX_POINTS 100
#define MAX_POLYGONS 100

typedef struct{
    int polyid[MAX_POINTS];
    int npoints[MAX_POINTS];
    double x[MAX_POINTS];
    //Stage1
    double y[MAX_POINTS];
    double perimeter;
    double eccentricity;
    double area;
} Polygon;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Polygon Total_poly[MAX_POLYGONS];
    int count=0;
    int i,j,k,l;
    printf("Stage 1");
    printf("=====");
    while(scanf("%d %d",&Total_poly[count].polyid,&Total_poly[count].npoints)==2){
        printf("First Polygon %d",Total_poly[count].polyid);
         printf("x_val      y_val");
        for(i=0;i<Total_poly[count].npoints;i++){
             while(scanf("%lf %lf",&Total_poly[count].x[i],
                        &Total_poly[count].y[i])==2){
             printf("%d     %d",Total_poly[count].x[i],
                        Total_poly[count].y[i]);
                        }
        }
    }

    //Stage2
    //Stage3
return 0;

}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I think you need to redefine your structure. There's too many arrays in it. See http://ideone.com/YOSjYt

Comment: The struct array is quite a lot for a stack variable. Suggest obtaining memory with `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

`Polygon Total_poly[MAX_POLYGONS];` uses more than 240 KB of stack space. It may cause problems on some systems.  You should probably make this array global or allocate it with `malloc()`.

There is a bug here:

```
printf("%d     %d",Total_poly[count].x[i],
                    Total_poly[count].y[i]);
```

You use `%d`, but you pass `double` values as arguments.  You should use `%e`, `%f` or `%g`.

You should configure your compiler to produce useful warning messages that would prevent this kind of mistake.  `gcc -Wall -W -Werror` is a good start.